# How to resolve Microsoft Excel for Max OS X Yosemite error "Cannot use object linking and embedding"?

Tags: macos, ms-office

What is the best way to resolve Microsoft Excel for Mac OS X Yosemite error  "Cannot use object linking and embedding"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an effective method detailed within the [Microsoft Community Forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macexcel/excel-for-mac-2016-cannot-use-object-linking-and/aef0051b-7902-4363-93d4-539057e6ddd6):

1. Open **Finder** and search for the following file: `com.microsoft.Office365.plist.`
2. Delete aforementioned file.
3. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and I solved it like below.

Please open terminal and do it like this.

```
cd Users/<username>/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office

rm -rf com.microsoft.Office365.plist.
```